# Ruby on Rails Aws SDK v2 constant 'Aws' undefined constant error in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am successfully using 'Aws' (Amazon Web Services) SDK version 2 (NOT 'AWS' in capital letters as that is SDK version 1 namespace, I am using 'Aws' version 2) and the namespace constant 'Aws' is known at the rails controller level in code, but if I go one level deeper, say trying to use 'Aws' in a model created by the same controller, the 'Aws' namespace is not known.  I get an undefined constant 'Aws' error.

My assumption is that Aws toolkit is initialized by including the gem in the Gemfile and it is there and all that appears to be correct. bundle check indicates all are resolved, and as I said it works in the Controller, but not in model class code.

I am circumventing this by injecting the Aws SDK into the models but I don't think this is the correct way, maybe it is??? I am new to Ruby and Rails so if you can give me advice or help me get setup so that the Aws toolkit is known globally as I had anticipated, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u post the whole error trace. Aws gem includes all its required files during rails boot, so it should work in model.

Comment: I don't have an error trace persay. I can see Aws in controller and a depth of one class below it if the controller initializes the object, and then if that class initializes another object I cannot see AWS or Aws at next depth unless I scope with ::Aws or ::Aws then I can see at a depth of 2 below the controller. Is this normal or documented somewhere?

Comment: Oh and I ran bundle recently, so not sure if that fixed things to the point I decribed above as before I could not see Aws or AWS one depth below controller, so maybe things are fixed and normal and I just don't understand the scope of modules completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the scope operator needed to be used normally. As a new Ruby user, I was not accustomed to constants not being available globally, therefore the explanation of why the scope operator was needed is somewhat explained by these references:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Ruby dot "." and double Colon "::" Operators:
You call a module method by preceding its name with the module's name and a period, and you reference a constant using the module name and two colons.

The :: is a unary operator that allows: constants, instance methods and class methods defined within a class or module, to be accessed from anywhere outside the class or module.

Remember: in Ruby, classes and methods may be considered constants too.

You need just to prefix the :: Const_name with an expression that returns the appropriate class or module object.

If no prefix expression is used, the main Object class is used by default.